# Javascript function change text colour

Tags: javascript, html

So I am creating an exam entry form for school and when a user enters anything wrong, the name of the field will turn red (what the user has input will remain the same) I need to be able to do this with an onclick event activated by my reset button however the function I have right now does not do this. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Exam Entry</title>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function validateForm() {
        var result = true;
        var msg="";

        if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter your name \n";
            if(result) document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
            document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }

        if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
            if(result) document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
            document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }

        if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value=="") {
            msg+="You must enter the exam number \n";
            if(result) document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
            document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }

        if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length!=4) {
            msg+="Your exam number must be exactly 4 digits \n";
            if(result) document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
            document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
            result = false;
        }

        if(msg != ""){
            alert(msg);
            return result;
        }

        var checked = null;
        var inputs = document.getElementsByName('examtype');
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i].checked) {
                checked = inputs[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        if(checked==null) {
            alert('Please choose an option');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return confirm('You have chosen '+checked.value+' is this correct?');
        }

    function resetNames() {
document.getElementById('name').removeAttribute('style')

document.getElementById('subject').removeAttribute('style')

document.getElementById('examnumber').removeAttribute('style')

        }
    }


</script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
    <form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
      <table width="50%" border="0">
                <tr>
                                <td id="name">Name</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder='Name' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td id="subject">Subject</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder='Subject' /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td id="examnumber">Exam Number</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="examnumber" size="4" maxlength="4" placeholder='No.'/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td><input type="radio" id="examtypeGCSE" name="examtype" value="GCSE" /> : GCSE<br/>
                                <input type="radio" id="examtypeA2" name="examtype" value="A2" /> : A2<br/>
                                <input type="radio" id="examtypeAS" name="examtype" value="AS"/> : AS<br/>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                                <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();" /></td>
                                <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" onclick="return resetNames();" /></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Help us to help you: please post only the relevant code - not all of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your closing braces may be in the wrong place... move one of the two closing braces at the end of your JavaScript to the end of the validateForm() function.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

**YOUR CODE**

```
function validateForm() {
 ....

    function resetNames() {
        document.getElementById('name').removeAttribute('style')
        document.getElementById('subject').removeAttribute('style')
        document.getElementById('examnumber').removeAttribute('style')
    }
}
```

**CHANGE TO**

```
function validateForm() {
 ......

}

function resetNames() {
    document.getElementById('name').removeAttribute('style')
    document.getElementById('subject').removeAttribute('style')
    document.getElementById('examnumber').removeAttribute('style')
}
```

Reason you have nested your function one inside another.